# Scaling proportionally on After Effects - Shift + click does not work!

Tags: after-effects

For the life of me, I can't tell what I'm doing wrong, but here we are!

I am on Mac, newbie on After Effects. I can scale anything (not proportionally) with the click on a corner but, unlike in Indesign or Illustrator, Shift + click just does not work! It kind of releases the frame, just like if I had clicked outside of it.

I am on Mac, After Effects CC. I verified the following:

- Shift is pushed (the "non permanent capital letter" key of the keyboard)
- Mode is "Selection tool" (the arrow)
- I am indeed clicking on a corner (where little square appears) and not on the side!

Yet it just deselects the whole thing and making me crazy! What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When I hold down shift, images and shapes scale proportionally. Just grab a corner handle and drag.

Alternatively:
Select the layer, press S to reveal the Scale parameter. Adjust that value. It will be proportional unless you unlink the x and y scales.

Comment: Right, thank you. What you describe is the behavior I expect, because its in Illustrator and the like. For the life of me, does not work in AE. Thanks about the Scale parameter. A little less practical in my case but useful!

Answer (score 0):

Click with no key held down, then hold down shift as you drag.

If you're holding the shift key while selecting it toggles the selection of the object that you click on, adding or subtracting it from the selected items.

So clicking on a selected object with the shift held down will deselect it.